Possible to mask reflections in Eevee?
I've tried outputting the Is Reflection rays into an AOV node to achieve this, but doesn't seem to be working, even though I got the expected result in the viewport, as you can see from the preview in the compositor below.

The brute force solution would be to render a flipped version of the objects that I need to mask the reflections of on a low render time configuration, such as Workbench with flat shading...
I'm open to inventive solutions.

You want the ball to reflect in the floor plane, right?

I want a mask of the ball's reflection in the floor. It is a reflective plane in this case, but if I could find a more general purpose solution that works on different reflective geometries, that would be better.
